# Array Classes - Error: Cannot Convert Parameter from 'double' to 'int'

Tags: c++, arrays, class, double

I was asking the community about this program earlier, but I've come into one final problem and a quick search on the internet shows me that it's a common one.

Below is my code followed by my build output

**Grader.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAXSIZE 100
#include "Grader.h"

Grader::Grader( ){
my_Values [MAXSIZE] = 0;
my_ValuesSeenSoFar = 0;
}

void Grader::addScore( int score ){
if( my_ValuesSeenSoFar < MAXSIZE)
    my_Values[my_ValuesSeenSoFar++] = score;
}
void Grader::addScores( int scores[], int size ){
    for(int i=0; (i < size) && (my_ValuesSeenSoFar < MAXSIZE) ; i++)
        my_Values[my_ValuesSeenSoFar++] = scores[i];
}
void Grader::clear(){
    for(int i=0;  i < MAXSIZE ; i++)
        my_Values[i] = 0;

}

int Grader::findBiggest() const{

   int max = my_Values[0];
   for(int i=1; i < my_ValuesSeenSoFar ; i++)
   {
        if( my_Values[i] > max)
            max = my_Values[i];
   }   
   return max;
}
int Grader::findSmallest( ) const{
    int min = my_Values[0];
    for(int i=1; i < my_ValuesSeenSoFar ; i++)
    {
        if( my_Values[i] < min )
            min = my_Values[i];
    } 
    return min;
}
```

**Driver.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Grader.h"
using namespace std;
int main( )
{
Grader g;
double d[5]= {99,70,85,93,84};
double e[4]= {100,81,60,91};

g.addScore( 75 );
g.addScore( 82);
g.addScores( d, 5 ); 

cout << "Best Score = " << g.findBiggest( ) << endl;
/// should give value 99
cout << "Worst Score = " << g.findSmallest( ) << endl;
/// should give value 70
g.clear( );

g.addScore( 50 );
g.addScore( 74 );
g.addScores( e, 4 ); 

cout << "Best Score = " << g.findBiggest( ) << endl;
/// should give value 100
cout << "Worst Score = " << g.findSmallest( ) << endl;
/// should give value 50 
}
```

And my error output is as follows

> ------ Build started: Project: Grader, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------ Build started 7/29/2013 2:55:05 AM. InitializeBuildStatus:   Touching "Debug\Grader.unsuccessfulbuild". ClCompile:   Grader.cpp
>   Driver.cpp \psf\home\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\grader\grader\driver.cpp(12): error C2664:
>   'Grader::addScores' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'double [5]' to
>   'int []'
>             Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
>   \psf\home\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\grader\grader\driver.cpp(22): error C2664:
>   'Grader::addScores' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'double [4]' to
>   'int []'
>             Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast   Generating
>   Code...
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:01.84
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Any ideas?

Comment: you are passing double array to a function which is expecting an int array.

Comment: @Jack I'm under the impression that I can't change the driver.cpp code--- However, under closer inspection the project doesn't explicitly say this is forbidden-- At my assumption, obviously, I ignored this obvious solution

Comment: please like/accept the answers you found useful. just mentioned since you are new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double d[5]= {99,70,85,93,84};
double e[4]= {100,81,60,91};
```

You `d/e` are defined as double however, `Grader::addScores` only takes int type.

```
void Grader::addScores( int scores[], int size ) 
g.addScores( e, 4 );
```

If you don't mean to make `d/e` double, tchange them to int type:

```
int d[5]= {99,70,85,93,84};
int e[4]= {100,81,60,91};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double d[5]= {99,70,85,93,84};
double e[4]= {100,81,60,91};
```

make it int.

Comment: call it like g.addScore((int)d, 5);